# How are dw and dd different from db directives for strings?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, nasm, masm

Let's say I want to define a initialized variable string before running my assembly program (in `section .data`). The variable I chose to create is called `Digits` and it is a string that contains all the hexadecimal symbols.

```
Digits: db "0123456789ABCDEF"
```

I defined the variable with `db`, that means *define byte*. Does this mean that the `Digits` variable is of 8-bits long? This doesn't seem to have sense for me because:

Each character in the string is an ASCII character, therefore I will need 2 bytes for each character. In total, I would need 32 bytes for the whole string!

So what does it mean when I define the variable as *byte*? *Word*? *Double word*? I don't see the difference. Because of my misunderstanding, it seems to be redundant to tell the type of data you need for the string.

**PD**: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168743/x86-assembly-which-variable-size-to-use-db-dw-dd) didn't help me to understand.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I know that *I define a byte variable*. What about if I *define a word variable*? Will it be 16 words long, e.g. 32 bytes long? This doesn't make sense for me... I'm missing something. Everything is built of bytes, thus shouldn't be everything a *byte variable*?

Comment: Example : `my_array DW 1,2,3,4` , this variable contains 4 values, each value is 2 bytes long, so the variable is 8 bytes.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez But in the case of strings? It's there where it's my misunderstanding, when I define strings.

Comment: With the types DB, DW or DD you are telling how much memory to reserve, but memory is always a bunch of bytes.

Comment: Pichi Wuana : what compiler are you using? In my compiler the data is arranged depending on the type : for type DB the bytes preserve the given order, for DW every two bytes change their order ('ab' stores as 'ba'), and for DD every 4 bytes change their order ('abcd' stores as 'dcba'). This order changes because the compiler stores the first byte in the lowest 8 bits, the second byte in the next 8 bits, and so on.  Maybe this is what confuses you.

Comment: Don't think of it as defining variables; you are defining labels to memory locations/allocations.

Comment: ASCII is 8 bit encoding (actually classic ASCII being 7 bit only, codes above 0x80 are platform specific, ISO-Latin1 encoding often used nowadays). So '0123456789ABCDEF` is 16 bytes, not 32. The "Digits: db" is sort of equal to do `Digits: db '0'` and then on new line doing `db '1', '2', '3', ...'F'`. (so the "Digits" label has address of byte containing '0'). The `'string'` syntax is shortcut to define values of multiple bytes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## NASM answer, MASM is totally different

One of the answers on the linked question has a quote from the NASM manual's examples which does answer your question.  As requested, I'll expand on it for all three cases (and correct the lower-case vs. upper-case ASCII encoding error!):

```
db   'ABCDE'     ; 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45                (5 bytes)
dw   'ABCDE'     ; 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45 0x00           (6 bytes, 3 words)
dd   'ABCDE'     ; 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45 0x00 0x00 0x00 (8 bytes, 2 doublewords)
dq   'ABCDE'     ; 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x44 0x45 0x00 0x00 0x00 (8 bytes, 1 quadword)
```

So the difference is that **it pads out to a multiple of the element size** with zeros when you use `dd` or `dw` instead of `db`.

According to [@Jose's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38860174/how-are-dw-and-dd-different-from-db-directives-for-strings#comment65085978_38860174), some assemblers may use a different byte order for `dd` or `dw` string constants.  In NASM syntax, the string is always stored in memory in the same order it appears in the quoted constant.

You can assemble this with NASM (e.g. into the default flat binary output) and use `hexdump -C` or something to confirm the byte ordering and amount of padding.

---

Note that this padding to the element size applies to each comma-separated element.  So the seemingly-innocent `dd '%lf', 10, 0` actually assembles like this:

```
;dd   '%lf',    10,        0
db    '%lf',0,  10,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0        ;; equivalent with db
```

Note the `0` before the newline; if you pass a pointer to this to `printf`, the C string is just `"%lf"`, terminated by the first `0` byte.

(`write` system call or `fwrite` function with an explicit length would print the whole thing, including the `0` bytes, because those functions work on binary data, not C implicit-length strings.)

---

Also note that in NASM, you can do stuff like `mov dword [rdi], "abc"` to store "abc\0" to memory.  i.e. multi-character literals work as numeric literals in any context in NASM.

---

### MASM is very different

See [When using the MOV mnemonic to load/copy a string to a memory register in MASM, are the characters stored in reverse order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427904/when-using-the-mov-mnemonic-to-load-copy-a-string-to-a-memory-register-in-masm) for more.  Even in a `dd "abcd"`, MASM breaks your strings, reversing the byte order inside chunks compared to source order.

Comment: Can you show an example for each of the other two cases, as you showed in a comment how it is with `dw`?

Comment: In conclusion, the mnemonic doesn't actually change something to the variable, only when it's tables?

Comment: @PichiWuana: That's not how I'd describe it.  `db` with a separate ALIGN directive would make more sense if you're going to access it as separate bytes.  Also, `db` just assembles bytes into the output file.  Variables are a higher level concept that doesn't have to map 1:1 with directives or labels.

Comment: Relating to assemblers which reverse the bytes in a string, compare [this NASM source](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/ldebug/file/69e00a339763/source/msg.asm#l1681) with [this A86 source](https://hg.ulukai.org/ecm/fddebug/file/b237abb3a356/DEBUG.A86#l6365): For A86, the two-byte `dw` string items are reversed by the assembler, so the source has to contain the "backwards" strings.

Answer (score 1):

I want to clarify something:

```
example: db 'ABCDE';
```

This reserves 5 bytes in total, each containing a letter.

```
ex2: db 1 ;
```

reserves a byte that contains 1

```
ex3: db "cool;
```

reserves 4 bytes and each byte contains a letter

```
ex4: db "cool", 1, 3;
```

reserves 3 bytes?

answers: ex4 is 6 bytes

Comment: Put this in a file, assemble it, and hexdump it to see what your assembler put there.  Your last example is wrong, `"cool", 1, 3` is 6 bytes total.

Comment: Also, this isn't really an answer.  It's kind of phrased as a question, although the first 3 examples are correct answers.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah i figured out the answer. Thanx

Answer (score -2):

For each character in the string "0123456789ABCDEF" you need just one byte. So, the string will occupy 16 bytes in the memory.

In case of this declaration:

**vark    db 1**

you can make this:

**mov     [vark],128**

and cannot:

**mov     [vark],1024**

but in this case:

**vark    dw 1**

you can.

Comment: The OP didn't specify MASM, where the directives after a label magically affect the operand-size of instructions referencing it.  Also, this doesn't answer the question at all, since this question is specifically about strings, not integer constants like in [the Q the OP linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168743/x86-assembly-which-variable-size-to-use-db-dw-dd) and said it didn't answer his question.