# Problems With "hello world" in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

So I am trying to make a programming language, which I translate to assembly and then compile. I've added to functionality to define a variable, but now having problems with printing variables.

This code in my language defines 2 variables x and y and prints y in the console:

```
(OUT)
(define y 'hello world')
(define x 'sup my bois')
(y)
```

and it translates to this assembly code:

```
    global _main
        
    extern  _GetStdHandle@4
    extern  _WriteFile@20
    extern  _ExitProcess@4
                
section .data
        
    y: dd 'hello world', 10
                
    x: dd 'sup my bois', 10
                
    y_end equ $
                
section .text
        
_main:
        
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax    

    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    (y_end - y)
    push    y
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20

    push    0
                
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
        
section .bss
```

but it prints both x and y and actually prints x with an indent:

```
hello world
   sup my bois
```

and when I also print x with this assembly code:

```
global _main
        
    extern  _GetStdHandle@4
    extern  _WriteFile@20
    extern  _ExitProcess@4
                
section .data
        
    y: dd 'hello world', 10
                
    x: dd 'sup my bois', 10
                
    y_end equ $
                
    x_end equ $
                
section .text
        
_main:
        
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax    

    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    (y_end - y)
    push    y
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20

    push    0
                
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax    

    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    (x_end - x)
    push    x
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20

    push    0
                
    push 0
    call _ExitProcess@4
        
section .bss
```

It prints like this:

```
hello world
   sup my bois
   sup my bois
```

I am not actually close to even beginner in asm, so it would be nice if you also explain how to solve it with the appropriate code...
p.s. I am on windows 10

Comment: That looks like NASM syntax for 32-bit x86 Windows.  What does any of this have to do with [arm]?

Comment: Have you tried using the Windows newline of CR LF, by uing `13, 10` at the ends of your `db` strings?  Oh, wait a minute, you're using `dd` instead of `db`.  Presumably the terminal is handling `0` bytes as spaces, not zero-width. (And MASM's weird and backwards design means that `0` bytes come first, unlike NASM ([How are dw and dd different from db directives for strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38860174)))

Comment: Or wait a minute, this *is* NASM, not MASM, sorry.  I'm not sure that duplicate explains it, since NASM's relatively sane handling of `dd "string"` won't put *leading* zeros.  You still want `db` instead of `dd`, though.  Oh, but you're printing both strings with one write since your `length` includes both due to where you put the `len equ $-foo`, so that will include `00` bytes.

Comment: Also, `y_end equ $` is just an obfuscated way to write `y_end:` - put a label at the current position.  Anyway, I'm not 100% sure the duplicates are the reason for the symptom you're seeing, but `dd` instead of `db` is an obvious bugs you should fix.  Also only line-feed without a preceding carriage-return can explain fully stair-stepped text, but not going to one tab-stop in I don't think.  It's probably the three `00` bytes after the newline in `dd 10` that are doing it.